# I need to write a dataset as XML data

Tags: c#, sql, xml, ssis, dataset

I need to generate the following xml output from the following dataset.  I have attached the dataset and the xml output sample. I am going to put the C# code in a SSIS script task. Can you guys help me to write to code in C#. I am a database guy but i really don't know how this XML works with dataset. I'd really appricate if you can help. Thanks In advance.

```
AGENTID STARTDAY    STARTMONTH  STARTYEAR   STARTHOUR   STARTMINUTE ENDHOUR ENDMINUTE   EXCEPTION
910180  5   5   2011    10  30  11  0   OPEN
910180  5   5   2011    11  0   11  30  OPEN
910180  5   5   2011    11  30  12  0   OPEN
910180  6   5   2011    17  30  18  0   OPEN
910180  7   5   2011    18  0   18  30  OPEN
911568  6   5   2011    16  30  17  0   OPEN
911568  6   5   2011    19  0   19  30  OPEN
911568  6   5   2011    19  30  20  0   OPEN
911568  6   5   2011    20  0   20  30  OPEN
911568  6   5   2011    20  30  21  0   OPEN
911568  6   5   2011    21  0   21  30  OPEN
911568  6   5   2011    22  0   22  30  OPEN
911568  7   5   2011    10  30  11  0   OPEN
911568  7   5   2011    11  0   11  30  OPEN
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<agentScheduleList>
    <agent>
        <id>470185</id>
        <schedule>
            <day>12</day>
            <month>8</month>
            <year>2002</year>
            <exception>
                <startdate>
                    <day>12</day>
                    <month>8</month>
                    <year>2002</year>
                </startdate>
                <starttime>
                    <hour>22</hour>
                    <min>0</min>
                </starttime>
                <endtime>
                    <hour>2</hour>
                    <min>0</min>
                </endtime>
                <code>Open</code>
            </exception>
            <exception>
                <startdate>
                    <day>13</day>
                    <month>8</month>
                    <year>2002</year>
                </startdate>
                <starttime>
                    <hour>2</hour>
                    <min>0</min>
                </starttime>
                <endtime>
                    <hour>3</hour>
                    <min>0</min>
                </endtime>
                <code>Lunch</code>
            </exception>
            <exception>
                <startdate>
                    <day>13</day>
                    <month>8</month>
                    <year>2002</year>
                </startdate>
                <starttime>
                    <hour>3</hour>
                    <min>0</min>
                </starttime>
                <endtime>
                    <hour>7</hour>
                    <min>0</min>
                </endtime>
                <code>Open</code>
            </exception>
        </schedule>
    </agent>
    <agent>
        <id>470185</id>
        <schedule>
            <day>13</day>
            <month>8</month>
            <year>2002</year>
            <offexception/>
        </schedule>
    </agent>
</agentScheduleList>
```

Comment: I have attached the dataset and the xml output sample.

Comment: since your xml values doesn't match your dataset, people might find it hard to create appropriate dataset to xml code.

Answer (score 3):

The DataSet class has a `WriteXml` function to write your data to a file, or `GetXml` to return it as a string. [The documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zx8h06sz(v=VS.100).aspx) has further explanation of customizing the output to get it to match exactly what you need, if your XML structure differs from your database structure.

Comment: I use XmlSerialize/Deserialize. I didn't realize there was a Write/GetXml. Nice to know...

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just use:

```
string xml = yourDataSet.GetXml();
```

You can read it back into a `DataSet` using the `DataSet` method `ReadXml`.

You can also use the following to get an `XmlDataDocument`:

```
System.Xml.XmlDataDocument xmlDoc = new System.Xml.XmlDataDocument(yourDataSet);
```